# Not able to bind grid in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am new with WPF.

I am attempting to bind datagrid in WPF.

**My Code:**

```
con = new SqlConnection(conClass.conSTR);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from login",con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt=new DataTable("login"); //DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
                da.Fill(dt);
                gv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="428" Width="503" Loaded="Window_Loaded" xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="This is a text block" Foreground="Red" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontStretch="Normal" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,29,0,0" Name="txtLoginID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <PasswordBox Name="txtPassword" PasswordChar="*" Margin="146,28,221,337"></PasswordBox>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,83,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"  />
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="247" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,130,0,0" Name="gv" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is no error in this code.

But still my grid is not bound to the table.

It just shows me horizontal lines.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I don't understand why i am facing this problem.

Please guide me.

**EDIT:**

Grid after `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True">`

[image]

Comment: what does your xaml look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">` to

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True">
```

Add  `RowHeight="25"`  to DataGrid

Comment: now its just showing me row headers, no data, other things as it as, showing horizontal lines below row headers.

Comment: @Freelancer add  RowHeight="25" to DataGrid

Comment: no , its making no difference, can see my edited screen shot[updated]

Comment: even i made it to 90, its as i uploded in my last screenshot.

Comment: thanx, row height was problem, i sorted it

Answer (score 2):

try changing as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
```

Comment: no difference, it is same as i have uploded below EDIT screenshot

Comment: Did you check whether your ItemsSource contains data, after loading from dt?
gv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your Xaml and set `AutoGenerateColumns="True".`

This allows the grid to create columns for your data. If you don't set it to true, you must add Column definitions for the columns you want to show.

Comment: now its just showing me row headers, no data, other things as it as, showing horizontal lines below row headers.

Comment: why its not getting created dynamically, as i do it in asp.net or windows applications?